# Pandas | Create new DataFrame merging rows with same values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in the following format:

```
Month      Value1        Value2      Name      Total
2020-08      12            23         'a'        35
...         ...            ...        ...       ...
```

However, for some reason, duplicate values appear.
For example, the following situation arises.

```
Month      Value1        Value2      Name      Total
2020-08      12            23         'a'        35
2020-08      0              1         'a'         1
...         ...            ...        ...       ...
```

I want the pair (Month, Name) to be unique, by merging the two rows.
This is a problem that I am currently struggling with.
I tried to create a new DataFrame with the following code

`df.reset_index().groupby([ "Month", "Name"],as_index=False)`

But the result of that operation returns a `DataFrameGroupBy` object when what I need is a new `DataFrame`.

Any help would be of great value!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the operation you want to use to combine the rows. For example, if you want to sum them, this would give you a new dataframe:

```
df.reset_index().groupby([ "Month", "Name"],as_index=False).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved the problem 